# Powershell how to make [string]::Format into a function

Tags: functional-programming, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

How can i change this string format into a callable function?

```
[string]::Format("param {0} param {1}, param {2} ",$param0, $param1, $param2)
```

So for example, I don't need to use [string]::format() each time i want to write-host

Something like the below.

logMessage("param {0} param {1}, param {2}", ,$param0, $param1, $param2)

Just not sure how to turn the [string]::format into a function.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
function Log-Message {
    param(
        [string]$Format,
        [Array]$Params = ""
    )

    $msg = [string]::Format( $Format, $Params )
    # Do something to actually log it, instead of just printing it back out
    # like I do on the next line...
    $msg
}

# For Testing Above Function...
$param0 = "foo"
$param1 = "bar"
$param2 = 42

# Using Parameter Names (cleaner)
Log-Message -Format "param {0} param {1} param {2}" -Params ( $param0, $param1, $param2 )
# Closer to what you were asking for...
Log-Message "param {0} param {1} param {2}" $param0, $param1, $param2
```

**Note:** in the second example, there is no comma between the format string and the first parameter.

Running the above will give you something like the following:

```
param foo param bar param 42  
param foo param bar param 42
```

Comment: So i did what you suggested, and I am just doing a simple Write-Host($msg);  And it's throwing an error.  ERROR: Log-Message : The term 'Log-Message' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
ERROR: if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Which part of the above did you do?  Somehow the above function isn't getting defined.  If you saved it to a file and ran it, did you load it with . -- For instance `. .\log-message.ps1`?

Comment: The Log-Message is being called within the program to write to the host.  I am not specifically calling Log-message from the command line.

Comment: function Log-Message
{
 param (
 [string]$Format,
 [Array]$Params
 )
 $msg = [string]::Format($Format, $Params);
 Write-Host($msg);
}

Comment: Ok so it seems to be working now.  The only issue is what if I don't have any params?  I kind wanted params to be optional.

Comment: Change the Params parameter to read: `[Array]$Params = ""`, and it'll behave.  I'll edit the answer to reflect this.